# rewrite url using htaccess?

Tags: .htaccess, url-rewriting

I want to redirect test.domain.com/auth/login to prod.domain.com/user by using .htaccess file. How will I do it?
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteBase /

```
#When your application folder isn't in the system folder
#This snippet prevents user access to the application folder
#Submitted by: Fabdrol
#Rename 'application' to your applications folder name.
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^app.*
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php?/$1 [L]


#Checks to see if the user is attempting to access a valid file,
#such as an image or css document, if this isn't true it sends the
#request to index.php
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?/$1 [L]
```

Thanks.

Comment: What exactly is your question here? Since you already use rewriting in your `.htaccess` style file we assume that you know how that works. So the question is: why can't you add another rule to implement what you ask about? We cannot help if you do not understand what your problem is!

Comment: Actually the htaccess file is is done by somebody else.. i really havent understood how htaccess file works.

Comment: OK, sure, we all start somewhere. I suggest you read the really excellent documentation about rewriting. You will find that although it is technical stuff it is possible to read and understand and it comes with a wealth of good examples that should answer all your questions: http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html

Comment: Thanks.. I will definitely read it